# Yaml file changes not being applied by kubectl apply

Tags: kubernetes

Basically, I've been trying to debug a kubernetes pod that has been in the Init:CrashLoopBackoff state for a while. I finally found a fix for it and applied the changes to the YAML file.

I changed the branch the container was trying to clone as it did not exist in the repository it was referencing. I changed the branch from courseList to staging.

I used the command kubectl apply -f config.yaml --validate=false and the changes should've applied. However, when I check the state of the pods, they are still down. When I use the command kubectl describe pods, I see in that the changes were not made as in the args section, I still see the branch is courseList.

How can I apply AND SAVE the changes to the yaml file successfully?

kubectl describe pods -n staging-jhub hub-5655445674-lkmhf (as you can see in the args section, branch is still set to courseList):

```
Name:         hub-5655445674-lkmhf
Namespace:    staging-jhub
Priority:     0
Node:         supergiant-1/172.27.188.206
Start Time:   Thu, 18 May 2023 15:41:00 -0700
Labels:       app=jupyterhub
              component=hub
              hub.jupyter.org/network-access-proxy-api=true
              hub.jupyter.org/network-access-proxy-http=true
              hub.jupyter.org/network-access-singleuser=true
              pod-template-hash=5655445674
              release=staging-jhub
Annotations:  checksum/config-map: 6c268aba85f2e5e2a61817417da69e881bfeef7d531c1da0fe857234fa0d767c
              checksum/secret: a9c0ca03f1c2f8b5b3ba11700efd8de88bcd482625fe55b5194da4c4465e32bd
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.95.198.186/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.95.198.186/32
              k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/network-status:
                [{
                    "name": "",
                    "ips": [
                        "10.95.198.186"
                    ],
                    "default": true,
                    "dns": {}
                }]
              k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks-status:
                [{
                    "name": "",
                    "ips": [
                        "10.95.198.186"
                    ],
                    "default": true,
                    "dns": {}
                }]
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.95.198.186
IPs:
  IP:           10.95.198.186
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/hub-5655445674
Init Containers:
  git-clone-templates:
    Container ID:  containerd://f3a04ffa871c964659474059a7ca1950667ebc83e06a2c7e8ae51dee6a3b810c
    Image:         alpine/git
    Image ID:      docker.io/alpine/git@sha256:66b210a97bc07bfd4019826bcd13a488b371a6cbe2630a4b37d23275658bd3f2
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
    Args:
      git clone --branch=courseList https://github.com/LibreTexts/jupyterhub-templates.git /tmp/jupyterhub-templates && cp -r /tmp/jupyterhub-templates/templates/* /templates && cp -r /tmp/jupyterhub-templates/static/* /static
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    128
      Started:      Thu, 18 May 2023 22:01:08 -0700
      Finished:     Thu, 18 May 2023 22:01:08 -0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  79
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /static from custom-templates-static (rw)
      /templates from custom-templates (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-nk2lb (ro)
Containers:
  hub:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         jupyterhub/k8s-hub:2.0.0
    Image ID:      
    Port:          8081/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      jupyterhub
      --config
      /usr/local/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py
      --upgrade-db
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:http/hub/health delay=300s timeout=3s period=10s #success=1 #failure=30
    Readiness:      http-get http://:http/hub/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=1000
    Environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED:        1
      HELM_RELEASE_NAME:       staging-jhub
      POD_NAMESPACE:           staging-jhub (v1:metadata.namespace)
      CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN:  <set to the key 'hub.config.ConfigurableHTTPProxy.auth_token' in secret 'hub'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /etc/jupyterhub/templates from custom-templates (rw)
      /srv/jupyterhub from pvc (rw)
      /usr/local/etc/jupyterhub/config/ from config (rw)
      /usr/local/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py from config (rw,path="jupyterhub_config.py")
      /usr/local/etc/jupyterhub/secret/ from secret (rw)
      /usr/local/etc/jupyterhub/z2jh.py from config (rw,path="z2jh.py")
      /usr/local/share/jupyterhub/static/external from custom-templates-static (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-nk2lb (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      hub
    Optional:  false
  secret:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  hub
    Optional:    false
  custom-templates:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  custom-templates-static:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  pvc:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  hub-db-dir
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-nk2lb:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 hub.jupyter.org/dedicated=core:NoSchedule
                             hub.jupyter.org_dedicated=core:NoSchedule
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff  16m (x1671 over 6h21m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container git-clone-templates in pod hub-5655445674-lkmhf_staging-jhub(41c352f3-d099-4669-947f-bc6581bf6cdd)
  Normal   Pulled   11m (x69 over 5h59m)    kubelet  (combined from similar events): Successfully pulled image "alpine/git" in 577.837946ms (577.860923ms including waiting)
  Normal   Pulling  62s (x80 over 6h21m)    kubelet  Pulling image "alpine/git"
```

kubectl get pods -n staging-jhub:

```
NAME                                 READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS         AGE
continuous-image-puller-5bcwt        1/1     Running                 0                37d
continuous-image-puller-rlrtq        1/1     Running                 1 (34d ago)      37d
hub-5655445674-lkmhf                 0/1     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   79 (5m10s ago)   6h25m
jupyter-rauyeki-40ucdavis-2eedu      0/1     Terminating             0                43d
jupyter-timstewart-40ucdavis-2eedu   0/1     Terminating             0                66d
jupyter-timstewartj-40gmail-2ecom    0/1     Terminating             0                61d
ngshare-586b877ff5-wg8sq             0/1     Terminating             0                67d
ngshare-85c7799db8-gw6hq             1/1     Running                 0                16d
proxy-85c45c65ff-fcdfv               1/1     Running                 0                34d
```

config.yaml file (change was made to line 114):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  replicas: 5
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
proxy:
  secretToken: 98768c9cb1e1376d335f29b778dbf6e6d9d2c44ceba4b06f17d5e7c6b53c5afc
  service:
    type: ClusterIP

imagePullSecret:
  create: true
  registry: libretextsregistry.ddns.net
  username: libretexts
  password: JVZJxTSm4wnTHVEjwkq49wy469eSS

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - staging.jupyter.libretexts.org
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - staging.jupyter.libretexts.org
      secretName: tls-cert

scheduling:
  userScheduler:
    enabled: false

cull:
  enabled: true
  timeout: 3600
  every: 300

singleuser:
  defaultUrl: "/lab"
  storage:
    capacity: 2G
  cpu:
    limit: 4
    guarantee: 0.5
  memory:
    limit: 7G
    guarantee: 7G
  image:
    name: libretextsregistry.ddns.net/binder-dev-libretexts-2ddefault-2denv-1cb626
    tag: "230d85d708cb6f6d1b6ba36bd2919a431eede445" # 3.3.1
  profileList:
    - display_name: "New Default Environment"
      description: "New environment with updated packages. Contains Python, R, Julia, Octave, SageMath and C++ kernels. Please report any issues to jupyterteam@ucdavis.edu."
      default: true
    - display_name: "R Studio"
      description: "Opens directly into R Studio."
      kubespawner_override:
        default_url: "/rstudio"
    - display_name: "High resource test "
      description: "Test for lots of resources"
      kubespawner_override:
        mem_limit: 32G
        mem_guarantee: 32G
        cpu_limit: 4
        cpu_guarantee: 4
  networkPolicy:
    egressAllowRules:
      privateIPs: true

hub:
  config:
    Authenticator:
      admin_users:
      - moorepants@gmail.com
      - rafeltstykket@ucdavis.edu
      allowed_users:
        # Do not remove this section. Users are permitted into the hub based on their email
        # as can be seen in the `extraConfig` section near the bottom of this chart
      - jasonmoore@ucdavis.edu
      - rafeltstykket@ucdavis.edu
    GoogleOAuthenticator:
      client_id: 988102819487-b7vs07so9qjtts93unkoc7avsdn2jiod.apps.googleusercontent.com
      client_secret: 4dI3vbpCef9K75uab_lhQRJp
      oauth_callback_url: https://staging.jupyter.libretexts.org/hub/oauth_callback
    JupyterHub:
      admin_access: true
      authenticator_class: google
  # Clone custom JupyterHub templates into a volume
  initContainers:
    - name: git-clone-templates
      image: alpine/git
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
      args:
        - >-
            git clone --branch=staging https://github.com/LibreTexts/jupyterhub-templates.git /tmp/jupyterhub-templates &&
            cp -r /tmp/jupyterhub-templates/templates/* /templates &&
            cp -r /tmp/jupyterhub-templates/static/* /static
      volumeMounts:
        - name: custom-templates
          mountPath: /templates
        - name: custom-templates-static
          mountPath: /static
  extraVolumes:
    - name: custom-templates
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: custom-templates-static
      emptyDir: {}
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: custom-templates
      mountPath: /etc/jupyterhub/templates
    - name: custom-templates-static
      mountPath: /usr/local/share/jupyterhub/static/external
  extraConfig:
    templates: |
      from jupyterhub.handlers.base import BaseHandler
      class AboutHandler(BaseHandler):
          async def get(self):
              self.write(await self.render_template("about.html"))
      class FAQHandler(BaseHandler):
          async def get(self):
              self.write(await self.render_template("faq.html"))
      c.JupyterHub.extra_handlers.extend([
          (r"about", AboutHandler),
          (r"faq", FAQHandler),
      ])
      c.JupyterHub.template_paths = ['/etc/jupyterhub/templates']
    ngshare.py: |
      c.JupyterHub.services.append({
        'name': 'ngshare',
        'url': 'http://ngshare.staging-jhub.svc.cluster.local:8080',
        'api_token': '1c29b8e60345a9f57f7c40dfc10256dad5c2de6083b3bb29c7fa8a98c79a23bb',
        'oauth_no_confirm': True})
    announcement: |
      # if you want to add an announcement onto our hub homepage / spawner pages, use the following:
      c.JupyterHub.template_vars = {'announcement': ""}
    allow-ucdavis-accounts: |
      from oauthenticator.google import GoogleOAuthenticator
      class UCDavisGoogleOAuthenticator(GoogleOAuthenticator):
          from tornado import gen
          @gen.coroutine
          def pre_spawn_start(self, user, spawner):
              auth_state = yield user.get_auth_state()
              spawner.environment = {'NB_USER':spawner.user.name, 'NB_UID':'1000'}
          def check_allowed(self, username, authentication=None):
              if not self.allowed_users:
                  return True
              if username.endswith("@ucdavis.edu"):
                  return True
              if username.endswith("@libretexts.org"):
                  return True
              if username in self.allowed_users:
                  return True
              return False
      c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = UCDavisGoogleOAuthenticator
      c.KubeSpawner.args = ['--allow-root']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing helm and kubectl

this part is a kubernetes template and can be applied with kubectl:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  replicas: 5
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

All the rest is an helm values file and should be used with [helm](https://helm.sh/) and not kubectl.

Also I would suggest not to use `--validate=false` with kubectl as you want the api server to validate that your file is valid

Comment: then would a command like helm upgrade be a valid way to update the yaml file?

Comment: or should i just separate the helm and the kubectl parts

Comment: If the kubectl parts is for something else I would totally separate them.

 If it's something needed for Jupyter hub to work I would create a new helm chart which has a dependency on Jupyter Hub and the deployment as a template. 

Either way helm upgrade won't be a valid way to update the yaml as long as you don't split it.